# how/when to use meta reply-to tag?

Tags: html, html5, meta-keywords

I was exploring meta tag and came across reply-to attribute. Can someone please give me an example of how to use it ? Also, is it recommended to use that attribute ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answers here on stackoverflow.com probably cover it - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3141705/what-is-meta-http-equiv-reply-to-content-adminexample-com. As one of the other answers says though, it's probably going to be a spam trap, so not recommended.